# Three fragments with views that have the same id causing odd behavior

Tags: android

I've created a viewpager which shows 3 similar fragments. These fragments have identical layout and the views in those layouts have the same id(eg: The RatingBar in DetailedPowerFragment has the id detailedRatingBar and so does the RatingBar in the DetailedWaterFragment)

However, when I attempt to set the value of the RatingBar with findViewById individually in each of the fragments it seems that a different RatingBar is found.

So

```
        final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    ratingBar.setEnabled(false);
```

in DetailedWaterFragment, would set the RatingBar in DetailedPowerFragment. Below you will see the code creating the viewpager if that is relevant - But what is causing this issue? Do I need to give a new id to all of my views to ensure that this doesnt happen?

```
    detailedFragments = new ArrayList<SherlockFragment>();

    detailedFragments.add(new DetailedPowerFragment());
    detailedFragments.add(new DetailedHeatFragment());
    detailedFragments.add(new DetailedWaterFragment());

    mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), detailedFragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Not sure to understand here, why have you created 3 times the same layout? Why not creating only one and use it for the 3 fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `getSherlockActivity().findViewById()` it returns you first view wit provided id from whole view hierarchy, so it can be not those rating bar that you currently see on the screen.

Yeap you could create 3 different fragments with a bit different view ids, this will helps. Also  you could modify your logic and invoke method to change rating bar of currently showed fragment.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. But what If all I want is to change the rating bar once instead of every time i change view? It seems like invoking a method to change the rating bar every time a new fragment is shown is a bit excessive.

Comment: @litemode If you want to synchronize your rating bars, probably you should move it out from ViewPager to parent's layout and use only one rating bar instead of 3 different bars in 3 fragments. I don't know what layout you want to create, so it's difficult to give you 100% solution.